# Excel 2010 R1C1 reference style inexplicably became selected

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

This really isn't a problem, it's just weird.  I opened Excel 2010 at work a few days ago, and noticed that my columns were numbered instead of lettered.  A quick Google search found the fix, which was that I needed to uncheck the "R1C1 reference style" option.  Easy enough, but I couldn't figure out how it became selected in the first place.

About 30 minutes later, a co-worker was trying to summarize some data in his version of Excel 2010, and asked me for help because his formulas were looking strange.  Sure enough, his columns were numbered instead of lettered.  So I, now looking like a computer expert, showed him how to correct the problem.  By this time I'm thinking that our IT department probably implemented some updates that caused this option to become selected.

Two days later, I open Excel 2010 on my home laptop, and-- you guessed it-- my columns are numbered instead of lettered.  So I'm thinking this was probably caused by a Microsoft update to Excel 2010.

Has anyone else experienced this?  Has Microsoft acknowledged this issue?  I didn't think that Microsoft was still supporting Office 2010.

Comment: It seems to be a macro issue. Do you have common macros in the office?

Comment: @MátéJuhász  I do use macros, but they run on my work PC, and no one else's.